# Создание человекопонятных ссылок блога на yii

Tags: yii2, yii, url, чпу

Есть блог статей, реализованных на yii1. Как можно создать ссылку так, чтобы название статьи являлось адресом url в адресной статье. Например, название статьи - "stackowerflow для чайников", url для нее - site.com/blog/stackowerflow-dlya-chainikov ?

Comment: Доброе утро. Рекомендую, для начала, перевести блог на вторую версию. После этого сделать то, что Вы хотите. По использованию чпу в yii2 вот ссылка https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-url-

Comment: Для начала обновить yii. Потом https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior